# Data not being stored when using Spring JPA with android

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am developing an app which would talk to the server which is developed using spring. I got to a point where we i was getting data from the google api and wanted to pass it to the spring server. But when i do pass it, the server accepts it but the data is not being stored in the mysql database.

Here is the code I am using:

This is the main spring application + controller:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = StudentRepository.class)

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class StudentController
{
    @Autowired
    public StudentRepository students;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getstudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Student> fetchStudents() 
    {  

        if(students.count() ==  0)
        {
            Vector<VideoList> no_video = new Vector<VideoList>();
            VideoList no_v = new VideoList("No Videos found", null, null, null);
            no_video.add(no_v);
            return no_video;
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/poststudent" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String putStudents(@RequestBody Student v )
    {

        students.save(v);

        return "Student Successfully Added";


    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchstudent/{str}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String searchStudent(
        @PathVariable("str")    String searchQuery
        )
    {   
        if(students.existsByEmail(searchQuery)){
            List<Student> sList = students.findEmail(searchQuery,new PageRequest(0, 1));
            Student s = sList.get(0);
            String str = "";
             Vector<CourseList> c = s.getCourses();
             Iterator<CourseList> it = c.iterator();
             while(it.hasNext()){
                 str.concat(it.next().toString());
                 str.concat("\n");
             }
             return str;
        }

        return null ;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addcourse" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String postCourse(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String course){
        List<Student> sList = students.findEmail(email,new PageRequest(0, 1));
        Student s = sList.get(0);
        CourseList c = new CourseList();
        c.setName(course);
        s.addCourse(c);
        students.save(s);
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is the Student class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Student {

    private String name;    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String email;

    private Vector<CourseList> courses = new Vector<CourseList>();//CourseList is just a class to store data about various courses.
    public Student(){}
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public Vector<CourseList> getCourses(){
        return courses;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setCourses(Vector<CourseList> courses){
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    public void addCourse(CourseList c){
        courses.add(c);
    }
}
```

This is my repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student,String>{

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE email = ?1")
    public List<Student> findEmail(String searchQuery, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(s) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM Student s WHERE s.email = ?1")
    public boolean existsByEmail(String searchQuery);


}
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password:root

# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And finally here is the android code to test the above:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    // Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // Profile pic image size in pixels
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail, course;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private Button SC;

    private String personName;
    private String personPhotoUrl;
    private String personGooglePlusProfile;
    private String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        course = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCourses);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
        SC=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Scourse);

        // Button click listeners
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        SC.setOnClickListener(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();


        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);

    }

    /**
     * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
     * */
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getCourses();
            SC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            course.setText(" ");
            SC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void getCourses(){
        new StudentSearch().execute();
    }



    private class StudentSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String >
    {

        String content = "";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.49.8:8080/searchstudent/"+email);

            StringBuffer studentString = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                InputStream responseString = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseString));
                String res = "";
                if ((res = reader.readLine()) == null) {
                    studentString.append("");
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.49.8:8080/poststudent/");

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put("name", personName);
                        jsonObject.put("email", email);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                        httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // writing error to Log
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    studentString.append(res);
                    studentString.append("\n");
                    while ((res = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        studentString.append(res);
                        studentString.append("\n");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return studentString.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (!s.isEmpty()){
                course.setText("Courses Taken:\n"+s);}
            else
                course.setText("No Courses Taken!");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                txtName.setText(personName);
                txtEmail.setText(email);

                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                // replacing sz=X
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Button on click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                // Signin button clicked
                signInWithGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                // Signout button clicked
                signOutFromGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.Scourse:
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SelectCourse.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-out from google
     * */
    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
     * */
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

}
```

I am a total newbie when it comes to developing spring code and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: i didn't understand your problem. you want to store data from spring server to database and read those data from an android application? or you want save data from android application ??

Comment: I was trying to save data from android application to database through Spring server

Comment: you must send data in JSON format to the server and then save them in your database.

Comment: I think i am sending the data in JSON format

Comment: so the server receive data as JSON format ? ok now you must parse this JSON data and insert it into your database